# Why helgrind complains on this program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, valgrind

I have such a class:

```
class A
{
public:
    void swap(A& a)
    {
        lock(mutex_);
        vec_.swap(a.vec_);
    }

    void push(int elem)
    {
        lock(mutex_);
        vec_.push_back(elem);
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec_;
    Mutex mutex_; // doesn't matter what kind of mutex is
};

A a, b;
```

thread #1:

```
a.push_back(5);
```

thread #2:

```
b.swap(a);
```

Isn't it thread safe? Valgrind says there is possible data race. The thing I suspect is that first swap is called, before locking proc switches to thread #1 and it modifies a, then switches to #2 and swaps content. But there shouldn't be a problem since actually the pointer is passed to the swap so even after modifying from #1 thread swap should see that change. Is this hard for valgrind to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not thread safe. The problem is that, although `A::swap` locks the mutex that belongs to `this`, it does not lock the mutex that belongs to the argument `a`, so one thread can be modifying `a` while another thread is swapping with `a`. You'll need to add a `lock` call in `swap` to lock `a`'s mutex.

Comment: @Curiosity - not stupid at all; it's the kind of thing that's easy to overlook.

Comment: Just adding a lock of the other object to swap may cause deadlock though. If `obj1` tries to swap with `obj2` at the same time `obj2` tries to swap with `obj1` and both lock themselves and then try to lock the other, things will not end well.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - good point. In fact, things will not end at all. Any time you're locking more than one mutex you have to do something to avoid deadlock. But that's a subject for a different question.